# When to use double braces {{}} in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Taken from the Angular documentation:

> [Angular Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)
>   Angular expressions are JavaScript-like code snippets that are mainly
>   placed in interpolation bindings such as

```
<span title="{{ attrBinding }}">{{ textBinding }}</span>
```

> but also used directly in directive
>   attributes such as `ng-click="functionExpression()"`.
>
> For example, these are valid expressions in Angular:
>
> 1+2 a+b user.name items[index]

However I'm a little confused as to when to use the double braces syntax `{{}}` and when not to. The documentation seems to suggest that you don't need them when using expressions within the directive attributes (see the ng-click example above).

Although the following code which works offers anecdotal evidence to the contrary:

```
<ul id="Menu">
        <li ng-repeat="appModule in applicationModules"
            id="{{appModule.Name}}"
            ng-class="{ 'selected' :  selectedAppModule == '{{appModule.Name}}' }" 
            ng-click="menuClicked(appModule.Name)">
            <a href="#Content/{{appModule.Name}}">{{appModule.Display}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Note how in the ng-class directive the double braces are used and inside the ng-click directive they are not.

How do you know when to use them and when not to?

Comment: you use braces when you want to get it's value, and you dont use braces when you want to use it as a variable

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on the directive attribute in question and the type of binding it uses. Further more it depends on what you intend in the given situation.

From your example:

```
ng-repeat="appModule in applicationModules"
```

No need for the braces as this expression is evaluated by angular inside the ng-repeat directive.

---

```
id="{{appModule.Name}}"
```

Here we need braces as we want the id to be equal to the value of the expression.

---

```
ng-class="{ 'selected' :  selectedAppModule == '{{appModule.Name}}' }"
```

I'm pretty sure this can be written as:

```
ng-class="{ 'selected' :  selectedAppModule == appModule.Name }"
```

And you get the same behaviour.

---

```
ng-click="menuClicked(appModule.Name)"
```

In this example we need the ng-click to be bound to the method named menuClicked.

---

Generally we use {{}} when we want to evaluate the expression and when dealing with attributes we don't always need to use {{}} as they are in many cases evaluated behind the scenes.

**Simple Tip** A rule of thumb for when {{}} is needed is by thinking of it as a wrapper for a `.ToString()`-method. Does converting the expression to a string make sense, then so does using {{}}. (Any counter examples are very welcome)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, that makes sense. You were also right about the ng-class it does work using the variable instead of the literal value.

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation. **Avoid using using interpolation `{{ }}`** when
the documentation says that the directive takes an expression, . In the case of `ng-src`, the documentaion explicitly says use `{{ }}`. If the attribute is not an AngularJS directive, use interpolation.

> ## Erroneous
>
> ```
> ng-class="{ 'selected' :  selectedAppModule == '{{appModule.Name}}' }"
> ```

The above example is an example of mixing interpolation and Angular epressions.

Instead use:

```
ng-class="{ 'selected' :  selectedAppModule == appModule.Name }"
```

From the Docs:

> #### Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice:
>
> - It increases the complexity of the markup
> - There is no guarantee that it works for every directive, because interpolation itself is a directive. If another directive accesses attribute data before interpolation has run, it will get the raw interpolation markup and not data.
> - It impacts performance, as interpolation adds another watcher to the scope.
> - Since this is not recommended usage, we do not test for this, and changes to AngularJS core may break your code.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - mixing interpolation and expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-)

---

### Update

Don't use interpolation with:

- `ng-selected`, see [AngularJS `ng-selected` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)
- `ng-disabled`, see [AngularJS `ng-disabled` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)
- `ng-required`
- `ng-if`
- `ng-show`
- `ng-hide`
- `ng-open`
- `ng-value`
- `ng-repeat`
- `ng-options`