# Difference between passing attribute to directive in {{}} curly bracket and without curly brackets in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I am trying to set watcher on an attribute in angular directive like this

```js
angular.module("myApp",[]);

angular.module("myApp").directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                $scope.$watch(function () {
                    return [attrs.attrOne];
                }, function (newVal) {
                   console.log(newVal);
                }, true);
            }
        };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div my-directive attr-one="{{x}}">{{x}}</div>
    <input ng-model="x" />
  </body>

</html>
```

In the above example I passed the ng-model in {{}} to the directive attribute and watcher works like charm

but when I try to pass ng-model directly to directive attribute the watcher doesn't work anymore, check the code below

```js
angular.module("myApp",[]);

angular.module("myApp").directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                $scope.$watch(function () {
                    return [attrs.attrOne];
                }, function (newVal) {
                   console.log(newVal);
                }, true);
            }
        };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div my-directive attr-one="x">{{x}}</div>
    <input ng-model="x" />
  </body>

</html>
```

I am not getting what magic is {{}} brackets doing here. Any explanation for some wise man?

EDIT: I don't want to create an isolated scope because the element on which it applies uses the parent scope inside it

Comment: This is a difference between literal strings and interpolated strings.  Check this out https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750.  It gives a good explanation of each.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use double braces {{}} in angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338926/when-to-use-double-braces-in-angularjs)