# Can't get value from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have this select and the values are displayed correct but how to I get the value of the selected option in my function `FilterByBrand()`?

```
<select ng-model="selectedBrand" ng-change="FilterByBrand()">
  <option ng-value="-1">--Alle Brands--</option>
  <option ng-repeat="x in Brands" ng-value="{{x.opt_Brand.Id}}">{{x.opt_Brand.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use curly braces (interpolation) inside the ng-value. Check this answer for a great summary of when not to use interpolation - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50419144/5867572

```
<select ng-model="selectedBrand" ng-change="FilterByBrand()">
  <option ng-value="-1">--Alle Brands--</option>
  <option ng-repeat="x in Brands" ng-value="x.opt_Brand.Id">{{x.opt_Brand.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh I have spent hours trying to solve this and it was that simple. Thank you :-)

Comment: Glad I could help - I have had issues with that one in tha past too :) - happy coding :)